# Custom post tag images not displaying with ACF

Tags: custom-post-types, php, tags, advanced-custom-fields

Using ACF i've added a custom image field to a particular set of custom post tags. The problem I have is that I cannot get the images to display. Yes, I have added an image to the tag and updated.

```
        $term_id = 26;
        $taxonomy_name = 'tags';
        $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

        foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {

            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
            $tag_image = get_field('tag_image');
            echo '<a href="?categories=' . $term->slug . '">'. $term->name . '</a>';
            echo $tag_image; //this bit doesn't work :(


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [ACF documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/), you must pass either the term and term ID or the term object to the `get_fields()` function for a taxonomy.

So in your case, you would replace `$tag_image = get_field('tag_image');` with:

`$tag_image = get_field('tag_image', $term);`